# Excel: Trying to count cells based on date, can't figure out SumIf

Tags: excel, function, date, spreadsheet

hopefully you can help me with this. I've been trying to figure it out in Excel myself, but I can't make the functions work and it's causing me to manually count the cells.

I've created a sample sheet on Google to show roughly what I'm trying to do;
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18bFBvtbK-3JDj6Z6_b6NHttaytApNvdfw92ZcI4ECws/edit#gid=0

I have a series of tests my personnel have to take annually, and I want to write a function that displays the total number of tests taken within the past year. Cell B1 would be the column title, B2-4 would display the date the test was taken, and B5 is where I want the number of dates in B2-B4 that are less than one year old.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please post a sample of your data or a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

If you want less than a year old from todays date then just count all values that are greater than 365 days ago,

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B4, ">"&(TODAY()-365))
```